# Can I checkout to most current commit on git?

Tags: git

I have a git alias `lg = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all`

when I run `$ git lg` and I can see below.

```
*   0c86f9e - (3weeks ago) WIP on master: 3c98495 Delete old depart info and blog section - me(refs/stash)
|\
| * 1790d55 - (3weeks ago) index on master: 3c98495 Delete old depart info and blog section - me
|/
* 3c98495 - (5weeks ago) Delete old depart info and blog section - me (HEAD -> master)
* ffa196a - (5weeks ago) Delete client list section - me
* 4934070 - (5weeks ago) Delete portfolio section - me
* f73d676 - (5weeks ago) Show custom categories about departments - me
| * a9a174a - (5weeks ago) tmp save - me (feature/tmp)
|/
* 1f420bc - (7weeks ago) blabla... - me (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
.
.
.
```

But I had a more commit logs after 0c86f9e. maybe like below

```
*   0111113 - (3days ago) blahblah - me (HEAD)
*   0111111 - (3days ago) blahblah - me
*   0222222 - (3days ago) blahblah - me
*   0c86f9e - (3weeks ago) WIP on master: 3c98495 Delete old depart info and blog section - me(refs/stash)
|\
| * 1790d55 - (3weeks ago) index on master: 3c98495 Delete old depart info and blog section - me
|/
```

I want to go most current commit. But I can't find log. How can I see log and jump?

Comment: `But I can't find log` ... I would say that in general if you can't see the commits in your branch via `git log`, then they aren't there.

Comment: Then I can't go to most current commit...?

Comment: If you ran `git reset` to move your branch name, you've told your Git to throw out the newer commits.  If you got them from some other Git, you can just get them from that other Git again.  If not, use your reflogs to find the commits you told Git to throw away, and be glad that Git secretly keeps them (without showing them to you) for an extra month or more by default.

Comment: Solved by using `git reflog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long-form way to get it is

```
git rev-list --all --reflog --date-order -1
```

and `git log` (naturally) also takes the `--reflog` option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the more recent commits you refer to are on the server, you need to pull.
Run `git pull`, or `git fetch` if you do not want to update your current local version.
The commits should then be visible.

Comment: Where are they then ?

Comment: They were on the local. I thought that commits were on the local master branch but It wasn't. After I checkout to the old commit, I can't go back to the most recent commit.